Spivak's differential geometry: Chapter 8 Theorem 11
I am having trouble understanding this claim about the existence of the sets $U_j$ in the following theorem from Spivak's differential geometry textbook.


I tried proving like this:
Firstly, we may take a covering which has no subcover and refine it to produce open sets $U_j$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ of compact closure such that the $U_j$ also yield a covering with no open subcover. We can then produce an associated exhaustion using the usual tricks $K_1=\overline{U_1}\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^{n_1}U_i=O_1\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{n_1}\overline{U_i}=K_1 $ and repeat.
I tried proving this statement for a while using this exhaustion $O_n$ with $K_n=\overline{O_n}$ and taking points $p_n\in O_n\setminus K_{n-1}$. Because of the non-compactness, $p_n$ is a proper sequence (never really ending).Next, the $p_n$ are connected to $p_{n-1}$ with overllaping charts with domain isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ because of connectedness or our manifold. I wanted these domains never to return to lower indices, but I cannot prove this!
Any suggestions?

Try taking a path that goes to infinity.

Could you add a little more detail?

For example, take a continuous path joining your $p_i$ to $p_{i+1}$ staying outside $K_i$, and chain these together to obtain a (continuous) path parametrized by $[0,\infty)$. Now (inductively) cover this path with open disks that overlap only consecutively.

I think this might work, but I cannot prove it. It is exactly my original problem: the trouble is that the existence of such a path is non constructive and uses connectedness of $M$, so we may return to lower indices.

No, you can choose the $i$th disk in the complement of the appropriate compact subset.

Is it really required that the $U_i$ are distinct?

No, the $U_i$ need not be distinct, there may be repetition.
